# E[z*x|G]=z*E[X|G]

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space. Let $G\subset \mathcal F$ be a sub-sigma algebra.

> prove that for z r.v s.t $z\in G$ then E[z*X|G]=z*E[X|G]

Our defenition of Y=E[X|G] is a r.v with the properties:

1. $Y\in G$
2. $\forall A\in G: E[Y*1_A|G]=E[X*1_A|G]$

The solution we've been told to do is starting with z to be indicator and then to build up sum of indicator and then positive function.

But I feel like my approach is much simpler so I would like to know what I'm missing.

We need to prove $\forall A\in G: E[zE[X|G]*A]=E[z*X*A]$ we'll notice we can define $g=z*A\in G$ and so $E[E[X|G]*g]=E[X*g]$. But this is the defenition of E[X|G].

I also havn't manage to prove it for indicators using a method that is diffrent from this approach.

Thank you very much,

Comment: What is $G?$ Always best to state up front what you are talking about.

Comment: 1) Please fix the notation. 2) "But this is the definition of $E(X\mid \mathcal G)$". The issue is that the definition is that $E[ E(X\mid \mathcal G)1_B] = E[X1_B]$ for $B\in \mathcal G$, which is not what you have written. Perhaps it is true that this extends from $1_B$ to $\mathcal G$ measurable functions (omitting some integrability conditions), but this is not part of the definition, and needs to be proved, which is what the standard arguments do.

Comment: ah I think I understand, The definition is only for indicators and I am supposed to show to any function.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The shortest demonstration I know of is this:
$$\mathbb E[zX\mid G]=\int zxdP_{X/G}=z\mathbb E[X\mid G]$$